# Why in Java pow(1, qNaN) is qNaN while in IEEE 754-2008 pow(1, qNaN) is 1?

Tags: java, standards-compliance

Why in Java `pow(1, qNaN)` is `qNaN` while in IEEE 754 `pow(1, qNaN)` is `1`?

Java:

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(1, Double.NaN)); // prints NaN (which is qNaN)

$ javac --version
javac 11.0.11
```

IEEE 754-2008, 9.2.1 Special values:

> pow (+1, y) is 1 for any y (even a quiet NaN)

Comment: You perhaps need to distinguish between Java the language and Java the API: float and double are IEEE754 floating point numbers, [according to the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3), but `Math.pow` is merely an API, for which the Javadoc [is quite explicit about the behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-): "If the second argument is NaN, then the result is NaN.".

Comment: I removed your "extra questions", as a question should ask only one question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is this way because the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,double)) for `Math.pow` specifies it to be so.  It says:

> `public static double pow​(double a, double b)`
>
> Returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument. Special cases:
>
> - If the second argument is positive or negative zero, then the result is 1.0.
> - If the second argument is 1.0, then the result is the same as the first argument.
> - **If the second argument is NaN, then the result is NaN.**
> - ....

As to *why* is it specified this way, the best I can suggest is to ask the people who specified it.

---

**UPDATE** - After some further research, I can now explain the divergence.

When Java was released, the published version of IEEE 754 was the 1985 version.  In 2008, a major revision of the 754 spec was released.  According to Wikipedia's [IEEE 754-2008 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008_revision#Clause_9:_Recommended_operations):

> "[Clause 9] is new; it recommends fifty operations, **including log, power, and trigonometric functions**, that language standards should define.

However, the Java designers had designed and implemented Java's `Math.pow` function at least 10 years earlier, and they had chosen to implement the `NaN` behavior as per their thinking.  Their thinking was different to the thinking of the IEEE 754-2008 standard committee.

Fortunately, the IEEE 754-2008 states that Clause 9 is optional, and not required for standard conformance.  The Java designers therefore took the route that was minimally disruptive for existing Java developers, and decided not to change the `pow` semantics to match the 2008 standard.  (I think this was the correct decision.)

<sup>Note: I am only inferring this reasoning.  AFAIK, the actually reasoning has not been published.</sup>

Comment: There are two schools of thought for how NaN affects the result, as explained in the [Function definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Function_definition) section of the [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) article on Wikipedia: 1) E.g. `pow(1, y)` is always 1, even if `y` is NaN. 2) Any operation involving NaN results in NaN. --- As the article says, the 2008 standard defines `pow(...)` to follow #1, and `powr(...)` to follow #2, so we can conclude that `Math.pow(...)` is the implementation of IEEE 754-2008 `powr(...)`, and that can't change, for backwards-compatibility reasons.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the divergence. Interesting.